# matrix inverse structure

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Let $A$ be an arbitrary invertible matrix, whose 2nd row is all zeros except the 2nd entry of the 2nd row is a nonzero element.

$$A= \left[ \begin{matrix}
   * & * & * & * & \cdots  & *  \\
   0 & * & 0 & 0 & \ldots  & 0  \\
   * & * & * & * & \ldots  & *  \\
   * & * & * & * & \cdots  & *  \\
   \vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots  & \cdots  & \vdots   \\
   * & * & * & * & * & *  \\
\end{matrix} \right]
 $$

Then, how to prove that $A^{-1}$ is a matrix whose 2nd row also is all zeros except the 2nd entry of the 2nd row is a nonzero element?

$$A^{-1}= \left[ \begin{matrix}
   * & * & * & * & \cdots  & *  \\
   0 & * & 0 & 0 & \ldots  & 0  \\
   * & * & * & * & \ldots  & *  \\
   * & * & * & * & \cdots  & *  \\
   \vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots  & \cdots  & \vdots   \\
   * & * & * & * & * & *  \\
\end{matrix} \right]
 $$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider the method of computing $A^{-1}$ through the adjugate matrix of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $AA^{-1}=I$.  In general, if you compute $AB$ with $A$ as above, then entries in the second row of the product are 
$$
a_{22}b_{2i}
$$
in column $i$ (use the across-down multiplication method and observe that almost all of the summands are zero).  In order for $B$ to be the inverse of $A$, then
$$
a_{22}b_{2i}=0
$$
when $i\not=2$, and
$$
a_{22}b_{2i}=1
$$
when $i=2$ (this are the entries of the second row of the identity matrix).

Answer (score 1):

To prove this I will be using a generalized $A_{n \times n}$ matrix for which $A_{2(1,\dots,n)} = (0,a_{22},0,\dots,0)$ where $a_{22} \ne 0$. To calculate the inverse of a matrix the simplest method is to use **Gauss-Jordan elimination** (Guass elimination for short). Using this method we can get:
$$[A_{n \times n}|I_{n \times n}] \xrightarrow{\text{Gauss elimination}} [I_{n \times n}|A_{n \times n}^{-1}]$$
Now we can start transforming our $A_{n \times n}$ matrix:
$$[A_{n \times n}|I_{n \times n}] =
\left[\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}
\begin{matrix}
    a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & \dots & a_{1n} \\
    0_{21} & a_{22} & 0_{23} & \dots & 0_{2n} \\
    \vdots & & & & \vdots\\
    a_{n1} & a_{n2} & a_{n3} & \dots & a_{nn}
\end{matrix}
& \begin{matrix}
    1_{11} & 0_{12} & 0_{13} & \dots & 0_{1n} \\
    0_{21} & 1_{22} & 0_{23} & \dots & 0_{2n} \\
    \vdots & & & & \vdots\\
    0_{n1} & 0_{n2} & 0_{n3} & \dots & 1_{nn}
\end{matrix}
\end{array}\right]
\xrightarrow{\text{row}_2/a_{22}} \\
\xrightarrow{\ \ \ \ \ }
\left[\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}
\begin{matrix}
    a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & \dots & a_{1n} \\
    0_{21} & 1_{22} & 0_{23} & \dots & 0_{2n} \\
    \vdots & & & & \vdots\\
    a_{n1} & a_{n2} & a_{n3} & \dots & a_{nn}
\end{matrix}
& \begin{matrix}
    1_{11} & 0_{12} & 0_{13} & \dots & 0_{1n} \\
    0_{21} & \frac{1}{a_{22}} & 0_{23} & \dots & 0_{2n} \\
    \vdots & & & & \vdots\\
    0_{n1} & 0_{n2} & 0_{n3} & \dots & 1_{nn}
\end{matrix}
\end{array}\right]
\xrightarrow{\begin{matrix}\text{row}_1-a_{12}\text{row}_2 \\ \text{row}_3-a_{12}\text{row}_2 \\ \vdots \\ \text{row}_n-a_{n2}\text{row}_2\end{matrix}} \\
\xrightarrow{\ \ \ \ \ }
\left[\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}
\begin{matrix}
    a_{11} & 0_{12} & a_{13} & \dots & a_{1n} \\
    0_{21} & 1_{22} & 0_{23} & \dots & 0_{2n} \\
    \vdots & & & & \vdots\\
    a_{n1} & 0_{n2} & a_{n3} & \dots & a_{nn}
\end{matrix}
& \begin{matrix}
    1_{11} & 0_{12} & 0_{13} & \dots & 0_{1n} \\
    0_{21} & \frac{1}{a_{22}} & 0_{23} & \dots & 0_{2n} \\
    \vdots & & & & \vdots\\
    0_{n1} & 0_{n2} & 0_{n3} & \dots & 1_{nn}
\end{matrix}
\end{array}\right]
:=[{\widetilde{A}}_{n \times n}|{\widetilde{I}}_{n \times n}]
$$
Let
$${\widetilde{\widetilde{A}}}_{(n-1) \times (n-1)} := {\widetilde{A}}_{n \times n} \backslash \{\widetilde{A}\text{'s 2nd row}\} \backslash \{\widetilde{A}\text{'s 2nd column}\}$$
$${\widetilde{\widetilde{I}}}_{(n-1) \times (n-1)} := {\widetilde{I}}_{n \times n} \backslash \{\widetilde{I}\text{'s 2nd row}\} \backslash \{\widetilde{I}\text{'s 2nd column}\}$$
We can see that ${\widetilde{\widetilde{I}}}_{(n-1) \times (n-1)} = I_{(n-1) \times (n-1)}$, since in $\widetilde{I}_{(n-1) \times (n-1)}$ only exactly the second row and the second column were modified. With the same reasoning we can see that $\widetilde{\widetilde{A}}_{(n-1) \times (n-1)} = A_{n \times n} \backslash \{A\text{'s 2nd row}\} \backslash \{A\text{'s 2nd column}\}.$

Let's invert $\widetilde{\widetilde{A}}_{(n-1) \times (n-1)}$ using the above mentioned (full) Gauss elimination:
$$[\widetilde{\widetilde{A}}_{(n-1) \times (n-1)}|{\widetilde{\widetilde{I}}}_{(n-1) \times (n-1)}] \xrightarrow{\text{Gauss elimination}} [{\widetilde{\widetilde{I}}}_{(n-1) \times (n-1)}|\widetilde{\widetilde{A}}_{(n-1) \times (n-1)}^{-1}] \qquad (*)$$

We can see that
$$\widetilde{\widetilde{A}}_{(n-1) \times (n-1)}^{-1} \bigcup \{A_{n \times n}\text{'s second row}\} \bigcup \{A_{n \times n}\text{'s second column}\} = A_{n \times n}^{-1}$$
Since throughout the Gauss elimination the second row and the second column don't need to be modified.

So
$$A_{n \times n}^{-1} =
\begin{bmatrix}
s_{11} & s_{12} & s_{13} & \dots & s_{1n} \\
0_{11} & \frac{1}{a_{22}} & 0_{13} & \dots & 0_{1n} \\
\vdots & & & & \vdots \\
s_{n1} & s_{n2} & s_{n3} & \dots & s_{nn} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
Where $s_{ij}$ are some values that come from the $(*)$ Gauss elimination.